# How to align children in a QHBoxLayout Left, Center and Right

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I have a **QHBoxlayout** with children set up as follows:

```
QHBoxlayout h = new QHBoxlayout();

QLLabel leftLabel = new QLLabel("Left");
QLLabel centerLabel = new QLLabel("Center");

QHBoxlayout rightContent = new QHBoxlayout();
QLLabel r1 = new QLLabel("2");
QLLabel r2 = new QLLabel("3");

rightContent.addWidget(r1);
rightContent.addWidget(r2);

h.addWidget(leftLabel);
h.addWidget(centerLabel);
h.addLayout(rightContent);
```

This will create a QHBoxlayout with all the children floated on the left. I would like **leftLabel** to be on the left, **centerLabel** at the center, and **rightContent** to the extreme right.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you all in advance.

**UPDATE**

I would like something like *left*, *center*, *right* below:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just add spacers between "Left", "Center" and "Right":

```
QHBoxLayout *h = new QHBoxLayout(&parentWidget);
h->addWidget(leftLabel);
h->addStretch()
h->addWidget(centerLabel);
h->addStretch()
h->addLayout(rightLabel);
```

Might be helpful to practice in Qt Designer.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on what you want, you could also define the alignment while adding the widgets like so:

```
auto h = new QHBoxLayout();
h->addWidget(leftLabel, 0, Qt::AlignLeft);
h->addWidget(centerLabel, 0, Qt::AlignCenter);
h->addLayout(rightLabel, 0, Qt::AlignRight);
```

See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addWidget) for more Information